# Can I resubmit an unpresented conference paper to the same conference?

Tags: publications, conference, etiquette

I submitted a paper to a major conference last year, it was accepted, but I had to withdraw from the conference before it could be presented. There is no proceedings for this conference. I am wondering the etiquette surrounding resubmitting the article to the exact same conference this year. Since the first submission, it has not been presented or published anywhere else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the COVID-19 pandemic, most people would consider withdrawing from an in-person conference to be a smart and ethical move.  In this situation, it should be fine to resubmit.  If the conference is peer reviewed, you should draw the conference's attention to the resubmission so they do not waste time re-reviewing a paper.

Do not make a habit of withdrawing papers.

Comment: Plus 1. OP: while informing the conference convey the idea that "you will be very glad to finally present as for before it wasn't really possible".